# java sort names with respect to location in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

program to get  name and location value from user

store in string array

display name value based on location in descending order

```
public class Samp
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String name[]=new String[5];
    System.out.println("enter the name");
    for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
    {
      name[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }

    String location[]=new String[5];
    System.out.println("enter the  location");
    for(int i=0;i<location.length;i++)
    {
      location[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
    //want to sort name with respect to location in descending order

    System.out.println("Name and location:");
    System.out.println(name[0]+" "+location[0]);
    System.out.println(name[1]+" "+location[1]);
    System.out.println(name[2]+" "+location[2]);
    System.out.println(name[3]+" "+location[3]);
    System.out.println(name[4]+" "+location[4]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want from us to do for your homework?

Comment: [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])), then iterate from end

Answer (score 0):

User `Arrays.Sort();`

```
 public class Test{


     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         String name[]=new String[5];
         System.out.println("enter the name");
         for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
         {
         name[i]=sc.nextLine();  
         }

         String location[]=new String[5];
         System.out.println("enter the  location");
         for(int i=0;i<location.length;i++)
         {
         location[i]=sc.nextLine();  
         }
         Arrays.sort(location); // asc
         Arrays.sort(location,Collections.reverseOrder()); //desc
         System.out.println("Name and location:");
         System.out.println(name[0]+" "+location[0]);
         System.out.println(name[1]+" "+location[1]);
         System.out.println(name[2]+" "+location[2]);
         System.out.println(name[3]+" "+location[3]);
         System.out.println(name[4]+" "+location[4]);
     }
}
```

Object Sort Using Comparator:

```
class Book {
    String name;
    String author;

    public Book(String name, String author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public static int compareBooks(Book a , Book b)
    {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name : " + name + "\t" + "author : " + author;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Book[] books = {
            new Book("Book 3" , "Author 1"),
            new Book("Book 2" , "Author 2"),
            new Book("Book 1" , "Author 3"),
            new Book("Book 4" , "Author 4")
    };

    Arrays.sort(books , Book::compareBooks);
    Arrays.asList(books).forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: *in descending order*

Comment: modified.check it hope it will help

Comment: Java program to get 'n' name and location(in String) from user and sort names with respect to location in descending...this is my question can u help me i am new to java

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         String name[]=new String[5];
     String location[]=new String[5];
     for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
         {
         System.out.println("enter the name");
         name[i]=sc.nextLine();  
         System.out.println("enter the  location");
         location[i]=sc.nextLine();  
         }

         Arrays.sort(location,Collections.reverseOrder()); //desc
         System.out.println("Name and location:");
         System.out.println(name[0]+" "+location[0]);
         System.out.println(name[1]+" "+location[1]);
         System.out.println(name[2]+" "+location[2]);
         System.out.println(name[3]+" "+location[3]);
         System.out.println(name[4]+" "+location[4]);
     }
}
```